# HTTP/1.1 406 Not Acceptable with Delphi and PHP

Tags: android, delphi, upload, firemonkey, indy

I have a simples `IdHTTP.Get()` to get a file contents, and `IdHTTP.Post()` to send a file via param, that I used with Delphi 2006. It worked like very well and fast. The first version was via IdFTP and it was very slow.

Now I copied that code to an Android App with XE8 and I get the error

> http1.1-406-not-acceptable

when I try to upload the file. The download via Get() is ok. It seems that the problem is with the response of the post, but I think it should at least finish sending the file, but does not.

IdHTTP.pas where the program breaks when I run it in Win32:

```
  case FHTTPProto.ProcessResponse(AIgnoreReplies) of
    wnAuthRequest:
      begin
        Request.URL := AURL;
      end;
    wnReadAndGo:
      begin
        ReadResult(Request, Response);
        if Assigned(AResponseContent) then begin
          AResponseContent.Position := LResponseLocation;
          AResponseContent.Size := LResponseLocation;
        end;
        FAuthRetries := 0;
        FAuthProxyRetries := 0;
      end;
    wnGoToURL:
      begin
        if Assigned(AResponseContent) then begin
          AResponseContent.Position := LResponseLocation;
          AResponseContent.Size := LResponseLocation;
        end;
        FAuthRetries := 0;
        FAuthProxyRetries := 0;
      end;
    wnJustExit: 
      begin
        Break;
      end;
    wnDontKnow:
      begin
        raise EIdException.Create(RSHTTPNotAcceptable);
      end;
  end;
until False;
```

I think, by reading your responses to other users questions about Indy, is that something is wrong with Encoding. But I confess I am very noob at this (did not needed to study encoding types until now) and do not understand the Delphi changes in this matter. Please help me! I don't want to use FTP again.

My Code inside of the try-except in the thread (i suppressed some URL part):

```
  Params := TIdMultipartFormDataStream.Create;
  Params.AddFile('dc',FilesPath+FileName));
  webRequest := TIdHttp.Create;
  webRequest.ConnectTimeout := 0;
  webRequest.ReadTimeout := 0;
  SaveCheck := webRequest.Post('http://alcantara.net.br/ristretto/?ac=ul', Params);
  ShowMessage(SaveCheck);
  Params.Free;
  aStream.Free;
  webRequest.Free;
```

Inside my hostgator server with download and upload code, it works when I test from the browser:

```php
if ((isset($_REQUEST['ac'])) && ($_REQUEST['ac']=='dl'))
{
    $LoginNX = @$_REQUEST['ln'];
    $LoginKX = @$_REQUEST['lk'];
    $DocumentNX = @$_REQUEST['dn'];
    $DocumentKX = @$_REQUEST['dk'];
    $FileName = md5($LoginNX.$LoginKX.$DocumentNX.$DocumentKX);
    if (file_exists($FileName))
    {
        echo file_get_contents($FileName);
    }
    else
    {
        echo '@newdoc';
    }
}

if ((isset($_REQUEST['ac'])) && ($_REQUEST['ac']=='ul'))
{
    $LoginNX = @$_REQUEST['ln'];
    $LoginKX = @$_REQUEST['lk'];
    $DocumentNX = @$_REQUEST['dn'];
    $DocumentKX = @$_REQUEST['dk'];
    $Document = @$_REQUEST['dc'];
    $FileName = md5($LoginNX.$LoginKX.$DocumentNX.$DocumentKX);
    try
    {
        //file_put_contents($FileName, $Document);
        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['dc']['tmp_name'], $FileName) === false) 
        {
            echo 'Erro: arquivo inválido!';
        }
        else
        {
            echo '@finish';
        }
    }
    catch (Exception $error)
    {
        echo 'Erro :' . $error->getMessage();
    }
}
```

The goal is to make a text editor that stores the files in cloud to avoid loss when loose cellphone or phone reset, but a plus is that it is cyphered with rca with keys not stored in the cloud.

Comment: 'and I get that error in Title'. ??? Your title is corrupted? Title of what?

Comment: The title mentioned Is the question title, not the program title.

Comment: Are you referring to something in the subject of your post?

Comment: Meanwhile you could have put all info in the body of your post.

Comment: The same error is now happening with my old desktop apps that used to work well (delphi and php)